# Why we can't use non-deterministic turing machines in this case?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, nondeterminism

Can you explain me why we can't show decidability of problem using non-determinism ? I know that this problem (described below) is not decidability, however I can't understand why following reasoning is not working.

Problem
Given a context free grammar $G$, does there exists a word $w∈Σ^∗$ such that $w^4∈L(G)$ ?

My reasoning:
Lets show Turing machine which decide this problem. Let machine guesses some word $w$ (it is possible because word is finite and $Σ$ is finite) and check if (using CYK algorithm) $G$ generates $w^4$.

I totally don't understand why this approach doesn't work. After all, non-determinism is about guessing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your reasoning is not wrong. But recall that decidability requires TM machine halt with YES if $\exists w \text{ such that } w^4 \in L(G)$ or NO if $\nexists w \text{ such that }w^4 \in L(G)$. In other words, the TM always halts.

In your approach the TM machine has to guess infinitely many strings and check if their forth power belongs to $L(G)$. A nondeterministic Turing machine cannot check infinitely many strings in finite amount of time.

Decidability problems efficiently solved by non-deterministic Turing machines are also solved by deterministic Turing machines. In other words, their computational powers are equivalent.

Comment: Indeed, a nondeterministic TM can't make infinitely many nondeterministic choices in finite time: at each state, there are only finitely many possible actions -- say at most $k$ of them. So, after $t$ steps, you can only explore $k^t<\infty$ possibilities.

Comment: I deleted an "efficiently" from the last paragraph, since the best known deterministic simulations of nondeterministic computations are exponentially slower. Also, your last parenthesis looks like you're claiming $\mathrm{P}\neq\mathrm{NP}$, which we don't know for sure.

Comment: @DavidRicherby As for your first comment, don't I say the same thing, namely "a nondeterministic TM can't make infinitely many nondeterministic choices in finite time"?

Comment: You say you don't think they can, which sounds uncertain. I'm clarifying that you're right. Also, the words you've put in quotes in your comment aren't a quote from your answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thank you for feedback, I'll update. And as the second comment, actually I don't claim $P\neq NP$, I mean DTM and NDTM give rise to two different time complexity classes. I'll update it too if it is also confusing.

Comment: @DavidRicherby just your opinion or possible pointers, what are the possible implications concerning NDTM model in case $P=NP$? For example, would we still need to consider NDTM model?

Comment: If $\mathrm{P=NP}$, nondeterminism would become a useful algorithmic tool. If you wanted a polynomial-time algorithm, you could design a nondeterministic one, which is often quite easy, and then determinize it. As long as the determinization process was reasonably efficient, that would give you a reasonably efficient deterministic algorithm for, say, 3SAT -- it's hard to see how to get such an algorithm otherwise. on the other hand, if determinization wasn't efficient (e.g., added a factor of $n^{100}$ to the running time), NDTMs wouldn't have much practical use.

Comment: Ahh, ok. In case of constraint on lenght of word (upper bound) this reasoning does the work, yeah? You are welcom in my threads!

Comment: @HaskellFun If you mean $w$'s length is restricted then there are finitey many possibilites. In that case your reasoning works.